# What is the exact commitment when commiting to an area51 site?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase, faq-proposed

I've lost whatever reference I had for what I actually committed to when I committed to Web Applications.

Could someone either point me to it, or post the text, so I can keep up my end of the deal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I clicked commit on a random proposal, and this is what I read:

> I commit to participate actively in [proposal], to visit at least three times per week, to ask at least three questions during the beta phase, and to answer as many questions as I can for at least three months.

Comment: Is it possible to fail the commitment requirements?