# What does it take for a commitment to count as "fulfilled"?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment, commitment-fulfillment

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to "follow through" on an area51 proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103294/how-to-follow-through-on-an-area51-proposal)
>   [What is the exact commitment when commiting to an area51 site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56185/what-is-the-exact-commitment-when-commiting-to-an-area51-site)

There is a same question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63973/when-is-a-commitment-fulfilled-on-area-51) but the answer is too specific and is not helpful for users who would like to know the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the [Area 51 faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)

> Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site by asking and answering a few questions, you'll be able to commit to another site. If you are very active, you may be able to re-use your commitment as soon as the second day of public beta. If you aren't active on the site, you won't be able to re-use the commitment until the end of the public beta (up to 90 days).

Comment: what do you mean by "a few questions"? Is the fulfillment of a user status decided by someone (as opposed to an automatic limit)?

Comment: @louis it is automatic, but we don't disclose the actual number because we feel it would lead to gaming

Comment: @Jeff Atwood:  Gaming?  I've fulfilled one commitment, and was informed that my commitment was fulfilled within minutes after I'd posted the last question.  If I need 17 questions and/or answers, how does that allow me to game the system?  If I'm going to flood the site with bad questions and answers, I can do that until either I hit the magic number or get the notification.

Comment: [as explained in this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63973/when-is-a-commitment-fulfilled-on-area-51), apparently the fulfillment calculation runs every 24 hours, so it's not immmediate. I think you'd hit the fulfillment limit before, and you also happened to post another q/a just before your status was calculated.

Comment: @Atwood - love the system of course.  When a user signs up to commit to work on a site, Area 51 gives the user the impression that they are signing a contract.  The big difference between that contract and real-life ones is that the terms of the commitment are not spelled out.  How can you ask people to commit their time and effort to something, while you can't even tell them the exact terms of that commitment?  Forgive me, but that sounds exactly like it makes the Stack Exchange system hypocritical on some level.

Comment: @Jeff: Given that it's ages ago that I committed to the beta, I have completely forgotten that pledge in Area 51. They should include that in the notification email we all got when the beta launched.